# Magento calculate product price based on number of products

Tags: magento-1.8, price

I don't this is possible or not. I want to calculate product price based on a number of products.

For example:

1. Product 1 price 100
2. Product 2 price 200
3. Product 3 price 300
4. Product 4 price 200

Customer addcart product 1, product 2, product 4.

Here final price is (200+200) = 400.

I mean if customer select more then 3 products `price` = `total price` - `min price`.

So, for the abouv example total = 400.

If posible to set rules tell me. Or suggest some idea to implement this